# I can't compare my file because error of failing to copy a file I do not need. Why?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Could not copy the file "D:\Dropbox\vb.net\packages\Selenium.Mozilla.Firefox.Webdriver.0.6.0.1\driver\wires-0.6.0-win.exe" because it was not found.    alarm
```

I have no idea why does the program need to copy    Selenium.Mozilla.Firefox.Webdriver.0.6.0.1\driver\wires-0.6.0-win.exe

I do not think there is anything in my project requiring it. Not anymore. If there is the error should be in the code that requires it. No. I go to nuget. I do not install Selenium. Not anymore.

What is going on?

[image]

I opened the alarm.vbproj file.

I found this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="packages\Selenium.Mozilla.Firefox.Webdriver.0.6.0.1\driver\wires-0.6.0-win.exe">
      <Link>wires-0.6.0-win.exe</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have no idea why those lines are in vbproj. Is it reference? I suppose I can remove it but that's not elegant. What can I do to get rid that reference say from normal visual studio interface.

I closed and reopened the project. This is what I found

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning     The file 'packages\Selenium.Mozilla.Firefox.Webdriver.0.6.0.1\driver\wires-0.6.0-win.exe' could not be added to the project.  Cannot add a link to the file D:\Dropbox\vb.net\packages\Selenium.Mozilla.Firefox.Webdriver.0.6.0.1\driver\wires-0.6.0-win.exe. This file is within the project directory tree.   alarm
```

Comment: Use Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run, "MSBuild project build output verbosity" = Detailed.  You'll get a trace in the Output window that ought to show why it thinks this file is important.  Copy/paste it into a pastebin if it doesn't make sense.

Comment: It's not a reference, it's an included file that the build machinery will copy to the output.  I'd recommend searching the solution to see if you can find anything that expects that exe file to be there.  If it was something that used to be used and was removed, it may be that the removal wasn't totally clean (e.g. if this was something that was added into the project file by hand); in that case, you may need to hand-edit the project file to remove it.  There are a number of things that can be done in MSBuild that aren't directly exposed through the Visual Studio interface.

Comment: It's a good idea that you could check your project to see if the properties of some project files are set to `Copy to Output Directory`. If it exists, you can delete these files, delete the `bin` and `obj` folders in the project directory and rebuild the project.